# Running old Ruby versioned app on newer version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to run a Ruby application that was developed in Ruby 2.1.2 on a machine that has Ruby 2.1.5 installed? I'm new to Ruby and I'm starting to think that's not possible. A newer version of Ruby cannot run an older one? Can someone confirm?

When I type "rails server" I get the error message saying "You ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)". One of the messages it gives me is "ruby-2.1.2 is not installed". And then it says "To install do: rvm install ruby 2-1-2"

I tried commenting out the ruby version in Gemfile and/or changing the version number but I get more error messages now:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think you can't? Have you tried it? Compared to `2.1.2`, `2.1.5` is just a set of bug fixes. Ruby follows [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/), which should help you understand the differences between any versions.

Comment: I've updated my question to show why I thought this.

Comment: You have enter wrong parameters in your database.yml. the connection parameters to connect your rails app to your DB is incorrect...

Comment: Can you explain why changing the version of Ruby requires a change in the database.yml file? It worked fine when I had it running in Ruby 2.1.5.

Answer (score 3):

Juste remove/comment your version of ruby specified in Gemfile like this

```
#ruby '2.1.2'
```

Or install ruby '2.1.2' with RVM (Ruby Version Manager) on your environment:

[RVM](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: He has 2.1.5 already - did you mean "install 2.1.2 with RVM"?

Comment: @Ray The errors above are unrelated to Ruby versions.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of recent history, the biggest shift in the Ruby language was between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9 where a number of things caused conflict due to changes in syntax and enforcing UTF-8 encoding.

Ruby 2.0 and 2.1 introduce more features but don't really impact backwards compatibility. It's very rare that a shift from 2.1.2 to 2.1.5 would cause problems with one exception:

- You will probably need to reinstall all your bundled gems.

Normally this is done with:

```
bundle install
```

Note that [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) itself is a gem, so you may need to install that if the `bundle` command is not available for that version of Ruby:

```
gem install bundler
```

If you're having a conflict due to mismatched Ruby versions in your `Gemfile`, edit that file to reflect your desired version.

Many multi-version Ruby managers like [RVM](http://rvm.io/) and [RBenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) use a `.ruby-version` file in the main application directory to specify this instead. This is a gentler approach than locking down your Ruby version in the `Gemfile` itself.

If you need to install a new version of Ruby on your server:

```
rvm install 2.1.5
rvm --default 2.1.5
rvm use 2.1.5
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

That should make it available.

Comment: When I try bundle install, it gives me the same mismatch error message.

Comment: I've amended the answer with responses to the details you've added in your question. Normally this is solved by installing the correct version, either 2.1.2 if you want to match exactly, or by bumping the requirement to 2.1.5 and using that instead.